# Taking users input into a string and writing it into a text file - Not working

Tags: c++, fork

My program shows a message to the user to give input which can be anything with no length limit.

```
using namespace std;

void child() {

   string i;
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter your text:"<<endl;
   getline(cin, i);
   cout<<endl;
   ofstream out;
   out.open("pro1.txt");
   out<<i;
   sleep(2);
   out.close();

}

main()
{


int r = fork();
if (r == 0) // child
{   
    child();
    exit(0);
} else if (r < 0) // failed to fork
{
    cout << "Failed to fork" << endl;
    // Throw exception
} else // parent
{
  // Code only executed by parent process
  cout<<"im in parent";
}

    // Code executed by both parent and child.
}
```

This input will be saved in a string which will be saved in the text file. I can't figure out what’s wrong with my code as it only takes the first letter and saves it in the text file.

Keep in mind this is being applied in a  child process!

Edit:
as you can see im forking a new process to do this job

Comment: _'Keep in mind this is being applied in a child process!'_ Why, what, when?!? Clarify this please. It's completely unclear what you're asking for. Please also show your actual input, and expected output!

Comment: do you have access to a debugger?

Comment: Works for me with multiple characters. It does stop reading at the first whitespace but that's the correct behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i added all my code by child process i mean im forking a new process

Answer (score 0):

Change `cin >> i;` to `getline(cin, i);`. `cin` once it finds white space it will stop reading.

Comment: `cin` stops by default at ' ' (space), not after reading one character.

Comment: Specifying `'\n'` as the third parameter is redundant as that is the default.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanx for the constructive comment.

Comment: `std::cin` stops extracting on __whitespace__ not just `' '`. That includes tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.